@parcel/transformer-babel, Styled Components, Styled Theming: "a problem adding namespaces" and "fake-element-placeholder-0"
I'm triyng to do a basic test to learn Styled Theming (of Styled Components) using Parcel.
I was just following Styled Theming docs for a basic test developing a fake theme for a fake Parcel React app.
These are the dependencies in the package json:
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
    "parcel": "^2.12.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},

"dependencies": {
    "@quickbaseoss/babel-plugin-styled-components-css-namespace": "^1.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "styled-theming": "^2.2.0"
}

This is the filesystem:
src/
    components/
        App/index.js
        Header/index.js
    styles/
        globals.js
        palette.js
        theme.js

This is the entry point App component:
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import Header from '../Header'
import { Globals } from '/src/styles/globals.js'

export function App(){

    const [headerThemeName, setHeaderThemeName] = useState(null)
    const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = useState('dark')

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={{ mode: themeMode }}>
            <Globals />
            <Header $themeName={headerThemeName}>
                <h1>Parcel APP</h1>
            </Header>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )

}

This is the Header component code:
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { headerColors } from '../../styles/theme.js'

const StyledHeader = styled.div`
    ${headerColors}
    padding: 100px;
`

StyledHeader.defaultProps = {
    $themeName: null
}

export default function Test({children,$themeName}){
    return (
        <StyledHeader $themeName={$themeName}>
            {children}
        </StyledHeader>
    )
}

This is the palette.js code
// Blacks
export const black = '#000000'
export const dark = '#2c2c2c'
export const gray = '#505050'

// Whites
export const white = '#ffffff'
export const light = '#b6b6b6'

// Colors
export const flashgreen = '#9dff2e'
export const magenta = '#e915d7'

This is the theme.js code
import { css } from 'styled-components'
import theme from 'styled-theming'
import * as color from './palette'

export const baseColors = theme('mode', {
  dark: css`
    background: ${color.black};
    color: ${color.gray};
  `,
  light: css`
    background: ${color.white};
    color: ${color.gray};
  `,
})

export const headerColors = theme('mode', {
  dark: css`
    background: ${color.dark};
    color: ${color.light};
  `,
  light: css`
    background: ${color.light};
    color: ${color.dark};
  `,
})

export const headerThemes = theme('name', {
  main: css`
    background: ${color.magenta};
    color: ${color.white};
  `,
  secondary: css`
    background: ${color.flashgreen};
    color: ${color.dark};
  `,
})

The Parcel build fails and this is the error:
@parcel/transformer-babel: C:\Sites\\_LAB\lab-parcel\src\components\Header\index.js: There was a problem adding namespaces to this CSS in the file C:\Sites\\_LAB\lab-parcel\src\components\Header\index.js. Error: <css input>:4:3: Unknown word  CSS:   fake-element-placeholder-0   padding: 100px;
I also tried to load the code on Code Sandbox just to give you a more comfortable enviroment to read the code but I've been unsuccessfull on reproducing a Parcel App so please ignore the console errors... just read the code ^^
I checked all... can't understand where the problem is but, according to the Parcel build error, it should be on the ${headerColors}interpolation in the Header component, so this point:
const StyledHeader = styled.div`
    ${headerColors}
    padding: 100px;
`

Can't undestand why...
I checked the syntax in the theme.js code and also checked the Styled Theming docs many times...
It seems all right to me...
Someone can help me to understand? I can't...
I spent many hours reading Styles Components docs... I don't want to give up... ^^
Thank you... ^^
